# find groups represented in multiple tests

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

In an R dataframe, I have pairs of events that occur under one of three conditions and want to find those pairs that occur in each condition. For example:

```
label1   label2   factor  value
 bob      ted        A     4
 bob     carol       A     3
 ted     carol       A     2
 bob      ted        B     3
 ted     carol       B     4
 bob      ted        C     2
 bob     carol       C     9
 ted     carol       C     6
```

How would I get the average for those pairs with entries in all three factors?

```
bob      ted         (4+3+2)/3 = 3
ted     carol        (2+4+6)/3 = 4
```

Nothing is computed for the pair of "bob" and "carol", because that pair has no value for factor B. The main question is how to identify those pairs that have values in each of the factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `label1` and `label2` and filter only those groups which has `all` values of "A", "B" and "C" and then take `mean` of those groups.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(label1, label2) %>%
  filter(all(c("A", "B", "C") %in% factor)) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(value))

# label1 label2   avg
#  <fct>  <fct>  <dbl>
#1 bob    ted     3.00
#2 ted    carol   4.00
```

---

Or if we do not want to hard code those values, we can get the `unique` before.

```
unique_value <- unique(df$factor)

df %>%
  group_by(label1, label2) %>%
  filter(all(unique_value %in% factor)) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(value))
```